# Why is 2-param drawImage faster than 9-param?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm finding that if I am drawing one HTML5 canvas to another, if I use the 2-parameter version of drawImage() where I simply provide the destination x and y coordinates, this is significantly faster than if I use the 9-parameter version, where I specify both the source and destination offsets and bounds. This is true even if the bounds specified in the latter are the same as the size of the source canvas in the former.

I'm seeing this in Chrome.

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating what I'm seeing:

```js
var cycleResults = document.getElementById('cycleResults');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

var canvas = $('.c')[0],
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  scratchCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  scratchContext = scratchCanvas.getContext("2d"),
  scratchCanvas2 = document.createElement('canvas'),
  scratchContext2 = scratchCanvas2.getContext("2d");
  
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
context.fillStyle = 'white';

scratchCanvas.setAttribute('width', 25);
scratchCanvas.setAttribute('height', 25);
scratchCanvas.style.width = '25px';
scratchCanvas.style.height = '25px';
scratchContext.fillStyle = 'white';
scratchContext.fillText('F', 12, 12);

scratchCanvas2.setAttribute('width', 8);
scratchCanvas2.setAttribute('height', 8);
scratchCanvas2.style.width = '8px';
scratchCanvas2.style.height = '8px';
scratchContext2.fillStyle = 'white';
scratchContext2.fillText('F', 0, 8);

function test1()
{
    context.drawImage(scratchCanvas2, 12, 4);
}

function test2()
{
    context.drawImage(scratchCanvas, 12, 4, 8, 8, 12, 4, 8, 8);
}

function test3()
{
    context.fillText('F', 12, 12);
}

// BENCHMARK ====================
btn.onclick = function runTests(){
  btn.setAttribute('disable', true);
  cycleResults.innerHTML = '';
  result.textContent = 'Tests running...';
  
  var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

  // add tests
  suite
  .add('test1', test1)
  .add('test2', test2)
  .add('test3', test3)
  // add listeners
  .on('cycle', function(event) {
    var result = document.createElement('li');
    result.textContent = String(event.target);
    
    document.getElementById('cycleResults')
     .appendChild(result);
  })
  .on('complete', function() {
    result.textContent = 'Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name');
    btn.setAttribute('disable', false);
  })
  // run async
  .run({ 'async': true });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/1.0.0/benchmark.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="c" width=25 height=25></canvas>
<ul id='cycleResults'>

</ul>
<div id="result">

</div>
<br>
<button id="btn">
Run Tests
</button>
```

In the end, I'm trying to determine if this is a valid optimization in lieu of using fillText(). fillText() is faster than the 9-param drawImage() call, but slower than the 2-param call. Is this expected, and can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: I can not give you the fully detailed reason, but the general case is the more parameters you use for any function the long it takes to make the call. I Also suspect there is additional overhead involved in the GPU fragment/vertex shader setup. Though I found on Chrome converting the image to a canvas gives you better performance with drawImage than using standard image. FF currently the best in terms of graphics and Script speed does not seem to care much about image source, or argument length.

Comment: @Blindman67 On Firefox 50, on a mac, the 2 argument version of drawImage is twice as fast as the one with 9 arguments, at least in the test above.

Comment: On Win10 Firefox 51.0b3 there is only 0.2µs (2/1,000,000th sec) between 2 and 9 argument versions when using my own benchmarker. Using yours and the difference is 3µs

Comment: correction (2/1,000,000th sec) should be (0.2 / 1,000,000th sec)

Comment: The 2-param version ultimately calls the same 9-param version, the difference in performance between the two tests is that in the 2-param version, we're drawing the entire source image, whereas on the other we're drawing only a portion of it. The former scenario is more likely to benefit from having all pixels stored in contiguous bytes in RAM which will help prevent L1 cache misses.

Comment: CPU caching has no effect on pixels stored in GPU. My tests on Chrome test for the same number of pixels (image 64/64) drawImage(image,0,0) and drawImage(image,0,0,64,64,0,0,64,64). The most likely cause of the slow down is the setting up of the Vertex and Fragment shaders required to render, which may be different for each call on some systems and not on others.

Comment: To compare a similar test, you need to draw a subset of your image in the 9-param test. If you use an image that is 512x512 and draw a 64x64 subset of it to your destination canvas, this should be significantly slower than drawing (an entire) 64x64 pixel image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2-param version ultimately calls the same 9-param version, the difference in performance between the two tests is that in the 2-param version, we're drawing the entire source image, whereas on the other we're drawing only a portion of it. The former scenario is more likely to benefit from having all pixels stored in contiguous bytes in RAM which will help prevent L1 cache misses.